# Spring security always giving 403

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I configured Spring security with a customer filter to authenticate using JWT.
Here's my config:

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthFilter(jwtManager, customerCredentialsDao), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Requested-With", "Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Filter:

```java
package catsit.config;

import catsit.authentication.CustomerContext;
import catsit.authentication.CustomerCredentialsDao;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtManager jwtManager;

    private final CustomerCredentialsDao customerCredentialsDao;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
        if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        String jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
        if (jwtManager.isTokenValid(jwt)) {
            CustomerContext userDetails = customerCredentialsDao.findCredentialsAndIdByEmail(jwtManager.extractEmail(jwt));

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities()
            );

            authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

It's working as expected but for some reason when I send a request to a random endpoint it returns 403. What I'm expecting is 404 but I can't seem to figure out why it's returning 403.
The requests to random endpoints are sent with a token so they are authenticated.

Comment: While I don't have an answer to your question, isn't it better to return 403 when the user attempts to access a non-existing endpoint, rather than 404?
After all, nobody is authorized to access an endpoint that does not exist. 404 might be more suitable for cases where there is no security, like a /resources directory.

Comment: may i ask why you are not using the built in JWT support that comes with spring security instead of writing a custom security solution which is bad practice?

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant but I'm using a custom filter for learning purposes.

Comment: Add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` to your `application.properties` and update your question with the log details